# How to check date time column value equals to current date in sql where clause

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a date time column in sql DB - named `check_time`. I want to write a select query where this `check_time` should be equals to today's date (no need to consider what time is. Only need to check current date).
For example `check_time` in table is inserted as `03/08/2017 12:00:00.000 AM`.
I have written like below

```
SELECT * FROM time_details  
WHERE check_time = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

But it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM time_details where (DATEDIFF(d, check_time, GETDATE()) = 0)
```

Comment: Which returns empty rows. Even though there is a column with value 03/08/2017 12:00:00.000 AM

Comment: The query above is 100% correct - If you are not getting any rows - there's something with the data... What is the date on the machine you are running the query on ?

Comment: yes the query was correct.machine date is shows as 3/7/2017 10:54:00 PM . This was the issue .

Comment: can we change the machine date?

Comment: Which machine is it? Windows ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137516/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-user2431727).

Answer (score 0):

Just `CAST` the today's date to `DATE`.

**Query**

```
select * from time_details 
where check_time = cast(getdate() as date);
```

Comment: shows error - Type date is not a defined system type.

Comment: @user2431727 :What is the data-type of `check_time` column?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
SELECT * FROM time_details where DATE(check_time) =CURDATE()
```

The DATE function is going to extract just the date from you datetime field while the CURDATE is returning the current date.

Comment: shows an error - 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question and you are referring to SQL Server, I though about MySQL. Just use GETDATE() instead of CURDATE and no function around your check_time field

Comment: corrected like above. returns no rows. SELECT * FROM time_details where check_time=GETDATE()

Answer (score 0):

Check with the sql query

SELECT * FROM  time_details where DATE(check_time)=DATE(NOW())

Comment: SHOWS 'date_format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

SELECT * FROM time_details where check_time =convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)